changing the theme from light to dark
I have a button to switch the theme from 'light' to 'dark'. I want to make the site darken when the button is clicked and vice versa. I tried to do it using javascript, but nothing works. I ask for your help.
html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

</head>

<body>
<div class="toggleWrapper">
  <input type="checkbox" class="dn" id="dn" />
  <label for="dn" class="toggle">
    <span class="toggle__handler">
      <span class="crater crater--1"></span>
      <span class="crater crater--2"></span>
      <span class="crater crater--3"></span>
    </span>
    <span class="star star--1"></span>
    <span class="star star--2"></span>
    <span class="star star--3"></span>
    <span class="star star--4"></span>
    <span class="star star--5"></span>
    <span class="star star--6"></span>
  </label>
</div>
    <header>Заголовок страницы</header>

    <nav>Меню навигации</nav>

    <aside>Боковая колонка SideBar</aside>


    <article>
      Контент - основное содержимое страницы.
    </article>

    <footer>Подвал сайта</footer>
</body>

</html>

css
body {
  background-image: url('https://img.razrisyika.ru/kart/137/1200/544003-fotografiy-v-horoshem-kachestve-29.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.toggleWrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 200px;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
}

.toggleWrapper input {
  position: absolute;
  left: -99em;
}

.toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 90px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #83d8ff;
  border-radius: 84px;
  transition: background-color 200ms cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
}

.toggle:before {
  content: 'AM';
  position: absolute;
  left: -50px;
  top: 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.toggle:after {
  content: 'PM';
  position: absolute;
  right: -48px;
  top: 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #749ed7;
}

.toggle__handler {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  background-color: #ffcf96;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  transition: all 400ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.toggle__handler .crater {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #e8cda5;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 200ms ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.toggle__handler .crater--1 {
  top: 18px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
}

.toggle__handler .crater--2 {
  top: 28px;
  left: 22px;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
}

.toggle__handler .crater--3 {
  top: 10px;
  left: 25px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
}

.star {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.star--1 {
  top: 10px;
  left: 35px;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 3px;
}

.star--2 {
  top: 18px;
  left: 28px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 30px;
  height: 3px;
}

.star--3 {
  top: 27px;
  left: 40px;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 3px;
}

.star--4,
.star--5,
.star--6 {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 300ms 0 cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
}

.star--4 {
  top: 16px;
  left: 11px;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 2px;
  transform: translate3d(3px, 0, 0);
}

.star--5 {
  top: 32px;
  left: 17px;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 3px;
  height: 3px;
  transform: translate3d(3px, 0, 0);
}

.star--6 {
  top: 36px;
  left: 28px;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 2px;
  transform: translate3d(3px, 0, 0);
}

input:checked+.toggle {
  background-color: #749dd6;
}

input:checked+.toggle:before {
  color: #749ed7;
}

input:checked+.toggle:after {
  color: #fff;
}

input:checked+.toggle .toggle__handler {
  background-color: #ffe5b5;
  transform: translate3d(40px, 0, 0) rotate(0);
}

input:checked+.toggle .toggle__handler .crater {
  opacity: 1;
}

input:checked+.toggle .star--1 {
  width: 2px;
  height: 2px;
}

input:checked+.toggle .star--2 {
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  transform: translate3d(-5px, 0, 0);
}

input:checked+.toggle .star--3 {
  width: 2px;
  height: 2px;
  transform: translate3d(-7px, 0, 0);
}

input:checked+.toggle .star--4,
input:checked+.toggle .star--5,
input:checked+.toggle .star--6 {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

input:checked+.toggle .star--4 {
  transition: all 300ms 200ms cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
}

input:checked+.toggle .star--5 {
  transition: all 300ms 300ms cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
}

input:checked+.toggle .star--6 {
  transition: all 300ms 400ms cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
}


You said you tried using Javascript ... please edit your question to include the Javascript that you tried, which didn't work. Also, take the time read this article and understand the techniques being used.

Does this answer your question? how to create a "light and dark" functioning button using JS?

I think it’s great that websites are adding support for dark mode, but I prefer not to build a switch into the website. The user has already set up their preference in their operating system, so all you need to do is add some media queries to adjust your site to follow suit. @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark). Yes, I know it’s trendy to have a button on your website ... it’s just totally unnecessary.
